# Inspecting a Docker BuildKit cache on registry

Tags: docker

The `docker buildx build` command accepts an option `--cache-to type=registry,ref=my/repo:buildcache` that pushes the build cache to the registry ([some docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit#registry-push-image-and-cache-separately)).

How can this cache be inspected?

- `docker buildx imagetools inspect my/repo:buildcache` crashes from a null pointer dereference.
- `docker manifest inspect my/repo:buildcache` triggers a 500 Internal Server Error.
- The Docker Hub website provides no information about a tag for a pushed build cache, except that it exists.

If I run a build with the symmetric `--cache-from type=registry,ref=my/repo:buildcache` option, it does print `importing cache manifest from my/repo:buildcache` but I don't know what it has imported.

Comment: In my case, 'docker buildx imagetools inspect my/repo:buildcache' can show cache name and mediatype properly. Your cache might not be set properly.